# SWT GridLayout and GridData alignment of composite blocks

Tags: java, user-interface, swt

I understand that I have layout but I have problem with setting achivementsChild next to each other. I want to make some alignment or something similar. Now they are standing one below other and I want to set one next to the other.

```
TabItem tbtmStudent = new TabItem(tabFolder_1, SWT.NONE);
tbtmStudent.setText("Student");

ScrolledComposite scrolledComposite_1 = new ScrolledComposite(tabFolder_1, SWT.BORDER | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
scrolledComposite_1.addMouseWheelListener(new MouseWheelListener() {
    public void mouseScrolled(MouseEvent e) {

        scrolledComposite.setFocus();
    }   
});

tbtmStudent.setControl(scrolledComposite_1);
scrolledComposite_1.setExpandHorizontal(true);
scrolledComposite_1.setExpandVertical(true);


List<STUDENT> allSTUDENTNodes = currentData.getStudentNodes();

Composite studentChild = new Composite(scrolledComposite_1, SWT.NONE);
studentChild.setLayout(new GridLayout());

for(STUDENT studentNode: allSTUDENTNodes){

    new STUDENTNode(studentChild, SWT.NONE, studentNode);

    Composite achivementsChild = new Composite(scrolledComposite_1, SWT.DEFAULT);
    achivementsChild.setLayout(new GridLayout());

    for(Achivements achivementsNode: studentNode.getAchivements()){
        new AchivementsNode(mscbcChild, SWT.NONE, achivementsNode);
    }
}
scrolledComposite_1.setContent(studentChild);
scrolledComposite_1.setMinSize(studentChild.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify how many columns you want when you create the `GridLayout`:

```
new GridLayout(numberOfColumns, columnsEqual);
```

`numberofColumns` is the number of columns you want.

If `columnsEqual` is `true` all columns will have the same width, if it is `false` they will have their preferred size.

Comment: Problem is for achivments because they are small block and student is bigger because of data, my question is how to sort achivments below student block